# Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/internshala/controller/signup.php on line 38

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I fix this error?

```
$qry = "select id,pwd,username  from users where username='jimmy'";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($row); // if uname/pass correct it returns must be 1 row
```

Comment: do not directly post variables. SQL Injection !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says  the parameter should be a `mysqli_result` object. So use the returned value from your `mysqli_query()` call

```
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
//                       ^^^^
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the problem

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($row);
```

this should be

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
```